# How to extend options in selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, selectize.js

I have this callback function, which creates list of categories on my page.

```
  this.getCategoryAdCount(function (categories) {
    //added selectize plugin to display multiply choice
    var values = categories.map(function (cat) {return { item : cat.id, text : cat.name + ' (' +cat.count + ')'}; }); //this is my data from the server
   this.$filtercat.selectize({
      plugins: ['remove_button'],
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      maxItems: 5,
      options: values,
      labelField: "text",
      valueField: "item",
      sortField: 'text',
      searchField: 'text',
      create: function(input) {
        return {
          value: input,
          text: input
        }
      }
    });
  }.bind(this));
```

It works good, but I have already existing function, which calls `.selectize` on every `$('select')` element on my page

```
  $('select').each(function(k, v) {
    var el = $(v);
    var options = SJA.Config.selectizeOptions;
    el.selectize(options);
  });
```

In this config I have list of options

```
selectizeOptions: {
  persist: true,
  maxOptions: 99999,
  dropdownParent: 'body',
  sortField: false,
  render: {
    option: function(data) {
      return '<div data-value="' + data.value + '" title="' + data.text + '" data-selectable class="option">' + data.text + '</div>';
    }
  }
},
```

So I don't want to call `.selectize` once again inside my callback function. Is it possible to extend somehow options only for the `this.$filtercat` variable without calling `.selectize` ?